# Crontab not running my shell script, but it runs manually (with an error)

Tags: linux, mongodb, cron

I am working on getting MongoDB daily backups stored on Amazon S3.  This is my first time working with crontab and shell scripts, and I am hitting a snag.  I found a script that seems to work, but only when I run it manually.  Here is what I have.

In crontab (while logged in as root).

```
* 2 * * * /mongo_backups/daily_script/mongobackup.sh
```

In my script (mongobackup.sh).

```
#!/bin/sh

MONGODUMP_PATH="/usr/bin/mongodump"
MONGO_HOST="Aspire"
TIMESTAMP=`date +%F`
S3_BUCKET_PATH="Aspire_Backups"

# Create backup
$MONGODUMP_PATH --host $HOST

# Add timestamp to backup
mv dump mongodb-$HOSTNAME-$TIMESTAMP
tar cf mongodb-$HOSTNAME-$TIMESTAMP.tar mongodb-$HOSTNAME-$TIMESTAMP

# Upload to S3
s3cmd put mongodb-$HOSTNAME-$TIMESTAMP.tar s3://$S3_BUCKET_PATH/aspire-mongodb-  $HOSTNAME-$TIMESTAMP.tar
```

If I manually run the script using sh -x ./mongobackup.sh this is what I get:

```
root@ip-10-4-149-188:/mongo_backups/daily_script# sh -x ./mongobackup.sh
+ MONGODUMP_PATH=/usr/bin/mongodump
+ MONGO_HOST=Aspire
+ date +%F
+ TIMESTAMP=2013-02-13
+ S3_BUCKET_PATH=Aspire_Backups
+ /usr/bin/mongodump --host
ERROR: required parameter is missing in 'host'

+ mv dump mongodb--2013-02-13
mv: cannot stat `dump': No such file or directory
+ tar cf mongodb--2013-02-13.tar mongodb--2013-02-13
tar: mongodb--2013-02-13: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
+ s3cmd put mongodb--2013-02-13.tar s3://Aspire_Backups/aspire-mongodb--2013-02-                                                                                                                        13.tar
mongodb--2013-02-13.tar -> s3://Aspire_Backups/aspire-mongodb--2013-02-13.tar  [                                                                                                                       1 of 1]
10240 of 10240   100% in    0s    42.59 kB/s  done
```

Like I said, I am new to crontab as well as shell scripts.  I understand the majority of what is transpiring here, but I am still trying to grasp the overall idea.

Comment: Can you run it with sh -x ./mongobackup.sh - output may help to see what's wrong.

Comment: Updated original post with the sh -x addition.  Still doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: It is not working manually either, that's the reason why it doesn't work when you add it to a crontab. You need a dump folder and a host param in the call, try it with those and post the output

Comment: You have HOST, MONGO_HOST and HOSTNAME - I think as the answer below points out you need to clean up variable assignments.  Make sure you use consistent values (and remember, unset variable is blank or null in your shell script).

Answer (score 2):

In the script you have:

```
$MONGODUMP_PATH --host $HOST

# Add timestamp to backup
mv dump mongodb-$HOSTNAME-$TIMESTAMP
tar cf mongodb-$HOSTNAME-$TIMESTAMP.tar mongodb-$HOSTNAME-$TIMESTAMP
```

Meaning that you are using variables `$HOST`, `$HOSTNAME` and `$TIMESTAMP` that have not been declared previously.

Try to declare them like

```
HOST=$(hostname)
HOSTNAME=$(hostname)
TIMESTAMP=$(date "+%Y%m%d") # it will output 20130213
```